wxWidgets и Clang в Visual Studio. Можно ли использовать их вместе?
Я решил попытаться создать проект на Clang с библиотеками Boost и wxWidgets. Я установил Clang(LLVM) из инсталлятора Visual Studio. Могу ли я использовать его вместе с wxWidgets?
Если да, то может сказать как и где его установить для работы с Clang?

Да, можно. Clang в режиме совместимости с MSVC (который включен по дефолту) может использовать любые библиотеки от него. Поэтому брать wxWidgets там же, где бы вы брали его для MSVC (можно в vcpkg, можно самому собрать). Ну и на всякий случай, Clang можно также использовать в режиме совместимости с MinGW, если это нравится больше (тогда лучше переставить кланг из msys2, и оттуда же поставить wxWidgets).
